# How to denoise (noise removing) from image without losing the scale (original range of values) of pxiel

Tags: python, image-processing, noise, noise-reduction

I'm trying to remove noise from the image, a DICOM image, the range of pixel value in this type of image is between (-1000, 30000), I want to keep this range after the noise removal, for further calculation (such as STD, mean, etc)

I tried skimage.restoration methods, most of them use multiplication or a standardization so after the model it changes the scale to a whole different one, however, I've found a method called 'denoise_nl_means'

```
denoise_nl_means(image, patch_size=7, patch_distance=11, h=0.1, multichannel=False,
fast_mode=True, sigma=0.0, *, preserve_range=False, channel_axis=None)
```

If I set preserve_range to True then it returns ndarray of my image with the same range of original ndarray, if false it returns ndarray with a range between 0-1

Example

```
org = [[0,6], [5,6],[3, 6]] # scale between 0-6
after_noise_removel = [[0, 6], [6, 6], [3,6]] # same standardization
```

My question is what to search in google so I can find something such a method that saves my scale range after the process, or if you guys can suggest to me any methods that fit my needs!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the function  `denoise_nl_means` with `preserve_range=True`?

Comment: @The_spider nothing wrong with it, actually I want other functions to do as it's. For the preserver_range in the documentation "Whether to keep the original range of values. Otherwise, the input image is converted according to the conventions of img_as_float"

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.denoise_nl_means

Comment: If there's nothing wrong with it, then why do you need another function doing exactly the same?

Comment: @The_spider I doing research and I want more than one function for comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have filtering functions that work either in the 16 bits unsigned range (0-65535), or in the 0-1 range, floating-point (single precision), you can rescale the input values to match the requirements of the function. And after filtering, revert to the desired range.

In these two cases, there will be little loss of accuracy.

Comment: I'm looking for this because of my research, what method can rescale my image after the denoising method? is this loss significant, and changes the image's overall look? if you are familiar with this kind of thing, could you suggest to me any of them?

Comment: @AhmedTareqF: rescaling is a linear transformation.

Comment: Using linear transformation could change the meaning for a certain spot, where in the analysis step I want to take 3 random spots and get the STD and mean etc, if I did it to the rescaled data using linear transformation it would give me a different answer, for example, std should be between 60-70 in a spot, but when I do it in the linear transformation rescaling it could give me a different range!

Comment: @AhmedTareqF: I did say that you undo the transformation after denoising, didn't I ?

Comment: Aha, now I get it, so you want me to do the scaling function for my data before sending it to the function using the same label function that was used for the function to get it back!!
didn't get it the first time, nice workaround for such a problem, thanks a lot!